# Question on sprint blocker and scope change

Tags: jira, agile, scrum

I've had three items assigned to me for the current sprint, two of them categorized as "blockers." The third item, in 'done status,' had a requirement change today.

I checked on what "blockers" mean, and they are things preventing you from getting a task done, right? So how can a goal itself be a blocker?

Also, I've been forced to do a lot of context-switching this week in the past. This is due to support for a couple of projects. However, it keeps me from settling into the blocker tasks.

By the way, I did get one blocker task reclassified as "major" due to effectively going over the Scrum Master's head. However, it was a non-customer-facing pilot project that I had been pulled into a call on. So both of the blockers came about this way.

The third project had a scope change due to a bug discovered (not my code), which affected me.

I'm not clear how to handle all this. Any ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 1):

The word 'blocker' does sometimes get used as a way to describe a very high priority task.

e.g. This ticket is a blocker for another team, so we must get it urgently fixed.

I agree this can be confusing!

Answer (score 1):

When a task (Task_1) is a 'blocker', it means that without solving it, another task (Task_2) in the team cannot be completed.. so 'blocker' tasks usually have a high priority.

So you can imagine both tasks have to be done in series, like in an Airflow DAG:

Task_1 >> Task_2